# Add Class to <body> tag after user has scrolled on a web page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a webpage and when the user has scrolled at any point, I want a div tag to change its class from "the top" to "the topscrolled".

I think you have to use the .scrollTop() to do this but not quite sure how to use it. Here is the html code

```
<div class="thetop">
        <?php /** Begin Header **/ if ($gantry->countModules('header')) : ?>
        <div id="rt-header">
           <div class="rt-container">
             <?php echo $gantry->displayModules('header','standard','standard'); ?>
             <div class="clear"></div>
           </div>
         </div>
         <?php /** End Header **/ endif; ?>
     </div>
```

I would also like to include the class named 'scrolled' in the body tag after the user has scrolled to apply separate css styling.

Comment: Why I downvoted this question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149138/133242

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the [ScrollTop](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/) function.

You can use it on the body like this :

```
$('body').scrollTop();
```

It will return the number of pixels scrolled.

Let's say you want to add a class after 500 pixels scrolled :

```
$('body').scroll(function(){
    // This function will be called at each scroll event
    if($('body').scrollTop()>=500){
        $('.thetop').removeClass('thetop').addClass('thetopscrolled');
        $('body').unbind(); // You don't want to add the class at each scroll event, just once.
    }
});
```